# Change the Bit Depth of a Custom File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression, bit-depth

I am trying to figure out a way to decrease the depth of a custom file type (the original bit depth of which is 16 bits) with matlab. The idea is to decrease the bit depth from 16 to 8 bits in 2 step increments to see how it affects the data. 
I know matlab has tools for changing the bit depth of image files but because this is a custom file type, I'm not sure they'll work in this context. (Because the rest of the compression script is written in matlab, finding a solution in the same language would be ideal). Any advice would be highly appreciated!